# Fecha y Hora en Android

Tags: android, date

Hola estoy tratando de enviar un formate `datetime` hacia la base de datos Mysql. estoy usando este fragmento de código:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Pero al enviar sólo me llega la el dia y la hora me llega en `00:00:00`

Me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El patrón o formato que le pasas a `SimpleDateFormat` le falta a agregarle:
`hh:mm:ss` formato de 12 hora, ó `HH:mm:ss` formato de 24 hora.

Te dejo dos ejemplos:

Ejemplo 1: formato en 12 horas:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = new Date();
String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(fecha);
```

Ejemplo 2: formato en 24 horas:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = new Date();
String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(fecha);
```

Comment: Perfecto señor! muchas gracias, pero me aparece con 3 horas más por que será?

Comment: Coloca el patron que estas utilizando y que te devuleve el format, para verificarlo.

Comment: Intentaste ejecutarlo sin pasarle el `Locale.getDefault()` o cambiando el valor del mismo, por ejemplo a `Locale.ENGLISH`